# How to load multiple files in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis

i am very new to ssis !

i wanted to know the below.

How to load multiple files into sql-server using ssis tasks?

I am currently working on datawarehouse. i have a bunch of files each in separate folders

```
the folders are

Myfolder
  ->subfolder_21-03-2009.txt
  ->Mysubfolder_21-03-2009.txt
Myfolder1
  ->subfolder_22-03-2009.txt
  ->Mysubfolder_22-03-2009.txt
Myfolder2
  ->subfolder_23-03-2009.txt
  ->Mysubfolder_23-03-2009.txt
```

I am able to load `Subfolder.*.txt` into sql-server DB(table 1) using `foreachloop` In ssis..

now can somebody tell me how'd i load `mysubfolder.*.txt` into Sql-server(table 2) DB

i want to load multiple files into sql-server in a single process.

`please somebody guide me !`

Comment: can you show us the package/code ?

Comment: Package is jus a for each loop with. Dft to load flat file into db with a String variable to iterate, but need to know how could I make a package that could I load 2 or more  different files into 2 or more  tables respecyively

Comment: i have i similar question in mind so i started a biunty on this :)

Comment: Duplicate of [Import text files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957451/how-to-import-text-files-with-the-same-name-and-schema-but-different-directories/19957728#19957728) but cannot be closed yet due to the bounty

Comment: @billinkc : i dont want to use the BIDS helper... i wnat it in SSIS only thnaks !

Comment: thanks for the guy who put bounty :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`I am currently working on datawarehouse. i have a bunch of files each in separate folders`

seeing this you need to refer this <kbd>[answer](http://dwbi1.wordpress.com/2012/05/26/how-to-populate-a-fact-table-using-ssis-part1/)</kbd> also you may <kbd>[check this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bca48559-60ad-4892-8da2-bee60f98b688/how-to-create-dimension-and-fact-tables-usinmg-ssis-pacakge?forum=sqldatawarehousing)</kbd>

and <kbd>[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957451/how-to-import-text-files-with-the-same-name-and-schema-but-different-directories/19957728#19957728)</kbd>

<kbd>[this is quite helpful  you can take a look here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/526833/SSIS-Load-Data-in-Dimension-Table-by-Merge-Join)</kbd>

To answer above you got a sequence container that executes task one after other :

### Snapshot 1

[image: Snap shot1]

### Snapshot 2

**You might want to give Mysubfolder.*.txt**

[image: Snap shot2]

### Snapshot 3[image]

**In the Data flow task you might be doing this**

Comment: thanks man ! i did the same way..is there any alternative to above,just for knowledege :)

Answer (score 1):

You allready have a "ForEachLoopContainer" looping in each folder to load "subfolder_*.txt" in table 1.

Why don't you create a second "ForEachLoopContainer" looping in each folder to load "Mysubfolder_*.txt" in table 2?

Then put those 2 "ForEachLoopContainer" in a sequence container and it's done.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a directory of files. Use a `ForEach Loop` container to enumerate all your files in the directory; because you have subfolders you must click the "traverse subfolders" option. Next you need to put a `Data Flow Task` in your `ForEach Loop` Container. Within the `Data Flow Task` you need to add a `Flat File Source`. Then you need to add a `Derived Column` transformation after your `Flat File Source`. Within your `Derived Column` you need to add the variable that you used to loop through the directory into the "Derived Column Name"; in the "Derived Column" put "Add as new column", and in the "Expression" you would use a `FindString` expression or a combination of `LEFT/RIGHT` expressions to grab the date from the file name. Then in your `OLE DB Destination` object you need to map your derived column to the relative column in your SQL-Server DB.

`FINDSTRING`: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141748.aspx

`LEFT/RIGHT`: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231081.aspx

Comment: Hmm..this is not what I need man I upvoted your other answer on my question! But this doesn't help me, can you please look above question again ... Thanks !

Comment: Did you check the "traverse subfolders" option in your ForEach Loop container?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to check to load 3 files with different format into 3 separate tables. Let’s say I have 3 files A, B, C with date as suffix and that changes every day. This is what I did.
[image: Image 1]

Create a ForEach Loop Container and set the Collection tab as below.
[image: Image 2]

Let’s make the filename date part dynamic using expression for each file connection managers.
[image: Image 3]

The final package would look like below.
[image: Image 4]

And voila!! The tables are loaded from respective files.
[image: Image 5]

Obviously this can be refined by using Foreach File Enumerator getting the fully qualified name of the file in a variable and then writing an Expression to parse it to channelize to different DFTs. Hope this helps.