# extracting .jpeg files from subfolders and putting them in another folder using SSIS

Tags: image, ssis

I have a folder that has around 400 subfolders each with ONE .jpeg file in them. I need to get all the pictures into 1 new folder using SSIS, everything is on my local (no connecting through different servers or DBs) just subfolders to one folder so that I can pull out those images without going one by one into each subfolder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create 3 variables, all of type String. CurrentFile, FolderBase, FolderOutput.

FolderBase is going to be where we start searching i.e. C:\ssisdata

FolderOutput is where we are going to move any .jpg files that we find rooted under FolderBase.

Use a Foreach File Enumerator (sample [How to import text files with the same name and schema but different directories into database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957451/how-to-import-text-files-with-the-same-name-and-schema-but-different-directories/19957728#19957728)) configured to process subfolders looking for *.jpg. Map the first element on the Variable tab to be our CurrentFile. Map the Enumerator to start in FolderBase. For extra flexibility, create an additional variable to hold the file mask `*.jpg`.

Run the package. It should quickly zip through all the folders finding and doing nothing.

Drag and drop a file system task into the Foreach Enumerator. Make it a Move file (or maybe it's rename) type. Use a Variable source and destination. The Source will be CurrentFile and the destination will be FolderOutput